# ReactiveUI Command with WCF resulting in Thread error on updating of Observable Property

Tags: wcf, reactiveui

I am attempting to make a WCF call using ReactiveUI commands and capturing the resulting string with ObservableAsPropertyHelper. With the code below I am receiving the following error message -

**"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it"**

**The WCF call returns but errors on accessing the ObservableForProperty - Message and/or when raising its PropertyChanged**

Let me know if anyone needs other details/code.

ViewModel: **UserService.Authenticate is proxy call to a WCF endpoint**

```
public class LoginViewModel : ReactiveObject, IRoutableViewModel
{
  public LoginViewModel(IScreen hostScreen , MainViewModel appRootViewModel, IUserService userService)
    {
        HostScreen = hostScreen;

        UserService = userService;
        Application = appRootViewModel;
        var canLogin = this.WhenAny(x => x.LoginName, x => x.Password, (l, p) =>
            !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l.Value) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.Value));

        LoginCommand = new ReactiveCommand(canLogin);

        var loggedIn = LoginCommand.RegisterAsync(_ => Observable.Start(() =>
            {
                var request = new Request
                {
                    UserIdentity = new User.Identity
                    {
                        Login = LoginName,
                        Password = new User.Password { Old = Password }
                    }

                };
                var authenticationResult = UserService.Authenticate(request).Authenticated;

                return authenticationResult ? "Login Succeeded...Continuing"
                    : "Login Failed...Please try again";


            }));
        loggedIn.Subscribe(s =>
        {
            if (s == "Login Succeeded...Continuing to Analytics")
            {
                HostScreen.Router.Navigate.Execute(Application);
            }

        });

            message = new ObservableAsPropertyHelper<string>(loggedIn,
            s =>
            {

                raisePropertyChanged("Message");

            });
```

**view code behind**:

```
public partial class LoginView : IViewFor<LoginViewModel>
{
   public LoginView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ViewModel).BindTo(this, x => x.DataContext);
        this.Bind(ViewModel, model => model.Password, x => x.password.Text);
        this.Bind(ViewModel, model => model.LoginName, view => view.userName.Text);
        this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, model => model.Message, x => x.message.Content);
        this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.LoginCommand, x => x.login.Command);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("ViewModel", typeof(LoginViewModel), typeof(LoginView), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    object IViewFor.ViewModel
    {
        get { return ViewModel; }
        set { ViewModel = (LoginViewModel)value; }
    }

    public LoginViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return (LoginViewModel)GetValue(ViewModelProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ViewModelProperty,
                value);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Fixed by telling the observer callbacks to run on the current synchronization context.

**.ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)**

So below is the LoginCommand Observable code to fix the above issues. Last line is the edit.

```
var loggedIn = LoginCommand.RegisterAsync(_ => Observable.Start(() =>
            {


                Session<NullT> init = new Session<NullT>
                {
                    SqlKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sharedKey"].ToString()

                };

                var initResponse = UserService.Initialize(init);
                var authenticationResult = false;
                if (initResponse.SessionOk)
                {
                    initResponse.UserIdentity = new User.Identity
                    {
                        Login = LoginName,
                        Password = new User.Password { Old = Password }
                    };


                    authenticationResult = UserService.Authenticate(initResponse).Authenticated;
                    return authenticationResult ? "Login Succeeded"
                        : "Login Failed...Please try again";
                }
                else return "Failed to Initialize.";


            }).ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current));
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of your code is correct (except for where you set `message`, just use `loggedIn.ToProperty`), but as I recall, WCF tries to "help you out" by fiddling with SynchronizationContexts, you need to disable this (I'm not sure how to do this though)

Comment: I've added                                                                                   [ServiceBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
[CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false)] to my service class and that did not help - in that its giving me the same result. A thing to note is that this works when I replace the authenticate call with a method stub - so Paul you are correct in that it has something to do with WCF

Comment: also does your suggestion about ToProperty work with regular properties or does the backing field need to be a ObservableAsPropertyHelper<string> message for it to work? On first pass, I am getting a null exception on message even when setting the initial value param like so --> loggedIn.ToProperty(this, x => x.Message, string.Empty);

Comment: Another observation is if successfully authenticated and routed to the MainView - I get {"The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this."} Somehow I'm thrown out of the current context because of WCF - whether I stay on the LoginView or navigate to another view?